# error: enum class * is not a class or namespace

Tags: c++

```
enum class myEnum : short {
    one = 11,
    two = 22,
};

#define FOO(param) myEnum param() {return param;}

class testClass {
public:
    FOO(myEnum::one)
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/z1j3sP7eW

I'm not sure why the compiler is telling me myEnum is not a class. Different compilers are telling me different errors, too.

Comment: What do you expect `myEnum myEnum::one() {return myEnum::one;}` to do?

Comment: Add the same code with the macro manually replaced to your question. Then explain what you expect it to mean.

Comment: You can't name a function `myEnum::one`, at least not a function defined in class `testClass`.

Comment: Basically what the others are saying: https://godbolt.org/z/KaqM35o8r

Comment: Ah. My function name is nonsensical! Thanks for spelling it out for me.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters pointed out, this error comes from the generated function name, *myEnum::one()* being invalid.